# How to change a value rank in a column MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table with a column which is defining a rank value for display position:

```
Unid | Rank | Name
10   |  1   | A
20   |  2   | B
30   |  3   | C
40   |  4   | D
50   |  5   | E
```

How to update the table for have Name E on the top of the list and followed by the A, B , C , D names ?

Comment: One option would be `ORDER BY ABS(SIGN(Rank-5)), Rank` without need of update.

Comment: Why do you assume and imply that any specific value for rank has any significance beyond ordering? Just set the value for E to 0 (or any other number less than that of A).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` with appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   [Unid] int,
   [Rank] int,
   [Name] varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO Data ([Unid], [Rank], [Name])
VALUES
   (10, 1, 'A'),
   (20, 2, 'B'),
   (30, 3, 'C'),
   (40, 4, 'D'),
   (50, 5, 'E')
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE d
SET d.[Rank] = d.[NewRank]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      [Rank], 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Name] = 'E' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [Name]) AS [NewRank]
   FROM Data
) d
```

Result:

```
Unid Rank Name
10   2    A
20   3    B
30   4    C
40   5    D
50   1    E
```